# How to display image instead of a value in Drupal 7?

Tags: theming, media

I'm having a field 'List (text)' in my custom content type as 'Select list' with Number of values as 'Unlimited', what I'm searching is to display an image instead of a value, for an instance I'm having values like Condo, Single Family & Multi Families so for these 3 different values I'm having 3 different logos which I want to display so what should I do to get this thing done?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest an idea I used in Views output — this may help you find a solution for your case. I needed to display an icon near an article depending on its material type. I added a hidden PHP field with the following code (image names are not directly the same as the type name, that was the brief :)):

```
<?php
switch ($row->type) {
case 'article':
  print 'articles'; break;
case 'gallery':
  print 'gallery'; break;
case 'music':
  print 'music';
}
?>
```

And then a “type” field, which had the following override:

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/my_theme/images/[php].png" alt="[type]" title="[type]" width="22" height="22" />
```

[php] is where Views output inserts the output of the PHP field I showed earlier. This same approach can be used to add a class to the HTML tag, and define a CSS image background for each class.

I hope this helps to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such an informative post, I still need some more info like what if I'm not using the Views module; instead of that, I'm trying to display the image directly onto my node URLs `http://localhost/node-name` where image is instead of the value of the 'Select List'. Thanks in advance!